# Matlab: Extracting Objects within a Cell Array that have a specific property value

Tags: performance, matlab, oop, indexing, cell-array

I'm working on a project written in object oriented Matlab (2016a) and I'm currently trying to optimise some code to improve the runtime. Using the profiler I have identified one possible performance improvement---there is a function we use *a lot* that seems particularly inefficient and not particularly "matlab" in its implementation.

Essentially, what I want to know is if there is an efficient way to index into a CellArray of classobjects to pull out only the ones that have a specific property value that we're interested in. Currently we do this using for loops and I'm wondering if there's something I can do to vectorise it or possibly to use some kind of logical indexing. Unfortunately my searches didn't seem to find an answer, logical indexing into CellArrays using objects doesn't seem to be something a lot of people want to do...

Here is a minimal working example of the function I'm trying to improve. Other bits of code for a MWE are below.

I'm aware that it may be wiser to fix this problem by changing the rest of the implementation to avoid having to do this at all. However, I would prefer to avoid doing that if possible.

EDIT: **In my typical use case the number of cell objects is small (around 10 or 20) but the inefficient method gets called a lot (thousands of times). So small array, many find operations.**

```
%% is there a "more matlab" / faster way to do this?
function outputCellArray = ThereMustBeABetterWayToDoThis(cellArrayOfClassObjects,arrayOfTypesToFind)
outputCellArray = {};

for iType = 1:numel(arrayOfTypesToFind)
    thisType = arrayOfTypesToFind(iType); % this line is the real bottleneck according to the profiler
    for iObject = 1:numel(cellArrayOfClassObjects)


        thisClassObj = cellArrayOfClassObjects{iObject};

        if (thisClassObj.specificEnumType == thisType) % this line is also quite slow
            outputCellArray{end+1} = thisClassObj;
        end
    end
end
```

Class Definitions:

```
classdef MyClass < handle %% dummy example class

    properties
        specificEnumType;
        x;
        y;
    end

    methods
        function this = MyClass(x,y,specificEnumType)
           this.specificEnumType = specificEnumType;
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
        end
    end
end
```

and another:

```
classdef EnumType < uint32 %%dummy example class
    enumeration
       Type0 (0),
       Type1 (1),
       Type2 (2),
       Type3 (3)
    end

end
```

Script to call the whole thing:

```
% use this script to call the whole thing

%% we have a cell array of class objects: they each have different enumTypes as a property
cellArrayOfClassObjects{1} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type0);
cellArrayOfClassObjects{2} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type1);
cellArrayOfClassObjects{3} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type2);
cellArrayOfClassObjects{4} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type3);
cellArrayOfClassObjects{5} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type3);
cellArrayOfClassObjects{6} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type2);

%% we want to find the ones that have these specific enumTypes
arrayOfTypesToFind = [EnumType.Type0,EnumType.Type2];

%% there must be a better way than this inefficient method
outputArray = ThereMustBeABetterWayToDoThis(cellArrayOfClassObjects,arrayOfTypesToFind);
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, that was a tricky one. To speed things up i would try to avoid the cellarray. In the function the cell is changed to an array of objects, then scanned as vector to speed up the loop, then changed back to a cell

Try this

```
cellArrayOfClassObjects=cell(10000,1);
for i=1:10000
    switch randi(4,1,1)
        case 1
            cellArrayOfClassObjects{i} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type0);
        case 2
            cellArrayOfClassObjects{i} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type1);
        case 3
            cellArrayOfClassObjects{i} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type2);
        case 4
            cellArrayOfClassObjects{i} = MyClass(rand,rand,EnumType.Type3);
    end
end

%% we want to find the ones that have these specific enumTypes
arrayOfTypesToFind = [EnumType.Type0,EnumType.Type2];

%% there must be a better way than this inefficient method
tic
outputArray = ThereMustBeABetterWayToDoThis(cellArrayOfClassObjects,arrayOfTypesToFind);
toc
tic
outputArray2 = ThereIs(cellArrayOfClassObjects,arrayOfTypesToFind);
toc


function outputCellArray = ThereIs(cellArrayOfClassObjects,arrayOfTypesToFind)
outputCellArray = {};
X=[cellArrayOfClassObjects{:}];%matrix of the cell 

for iType = 1:numel(arrayOfTypesToFind)
    %for each type check [X.specificEnumType]==arrayOfTypesToFind(iType)
    % then get the objects by X([X.specificEnumType]==arrayOfTypesToFind(iType))
    % then put them in cells mat2cell( X(...) , 1 , sum of those X(...)
    % and add the to the existing outputCellArray=outputCellArray+matcell
    % in one line
    outputCellArray=[outputCellArray mat2cell(X([X.specificEnumType]==arrayOfTypesToFind(iType)),1,sum([X.specificEnumType]==arrayOfTypesToFind(iType)))];
end

end
```

there might be a way to make it even faster by preallocating the outputarray. i am trying it now.
**edit**
that didnt work... but the first part should do it

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try and see how it works with the "real" classes that have a lot more going on.

Comment: Interestingly your method is faster when the cellarray of objects is large but slower when the cellarray object is small (try using an array of 10 objects but doing the find process a lot more). I assume this is because the overhead of doing mat2cell etc on a small number of objects is not worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a much better way (for my specific use case) that exploits the fact that the property I'm matching on is an enumerated type. That said, I'd still like to see if there are any more generic solutions. @Finn 's answer is equally good when the number of objects is large.

Here is my updated version. It may be possible to make further improvements.

```
function outputCellArray = ExploitEnums(cellArrayOfClassObjects,arrayOfTypesToFind)


typesCastToInts = uint32(arrayOfTypesToFind);

objectTaskTypesTakenFromArray = cellfun(@(x) uint32(x.specificEnumType), cellArrayOfClassObjects);

typesExistInBothArrays = ismember(objectTaskTypesTakenFromArray, typesCastToInts);
matchingIndices = find(typesExistInBothArrays);

if (~isempty(matchingIndices))
    outputCellArray = cellArrayOfClassObjects(matchingIndices);
end

end
```